# Wordsearch Trail: And now for something a little different

Tags: word-search

A Fun Friday Wordsearch!

Or is it...

Hidden in this wordsearch, is a trail of clues to lead you to one specific word within the grid. It's this specific word, and the trail you used to get there that I'm after.

*To begin, look for words adjacent to the green start-square, use these to find the next word; which again will be touching a new pair of clues.*

*Continue this until you have solved the board and retrieved the final word (which has no more new clues touching it).*

[image]

**Note**: *This was originally meant to be a bit of fun for a Friday, and definitely nothing involving cryptic logic or deduction. Below, see the first clue example worked out for you, which should make it clearer how to proceed.*

> From the start square, we have two words "touching" it. **hard** and **hat**. We can use these, and a bit of searching, to find the next word **helmet** `(I, 6) -> (N,6)`. "Touching" this are the words: "snake", "seasons", and "venonous". Out of those potential clues, two of them clearly go together **snake** and **venomous**, which suggest the next word you need in your trail. To re-iterate, each word has a **pair** of clues that you should use, any additional words are either red-herrings, or you will come back to later.

Also to clarify, as a simplification hint:

> All words that you need are on verticals and horizontals.

*Any feedback more than welcome as always, this is something I had in my head for a while and hope it's as fun & relaxing to solve as it was to design.*

*Spelling is en(gb)*

---

Text based grid (will reformat if a better way is suggested)

```
_   h   a   r   d   f   b   o   s   i   t   s   h   a   p   p   y   p   k   t   c
h   r   e   g   b   d   n   l   n   u   c   r   m   s   l   a   o   p   i   d   s
a   k   c   o   b   r   a   r   a   k   i   n   g   b   f   y   h   u   a   e   e
t   e   f   e   k   a   p   g   k   e   u   i   n   h   j   b   j   r   f   p   m
t   r   j   r   r   p   r   t   e   w   r   o   r   p   s   y   t   s   o   i   o
v   e   n   o   m   o   u   s   h   e   l   m   e   t   e   r   j   e   g   r   l
t   h   g   u   h   u   n   t   f   o   d   b   f   o   a   c   r   q   y   t   u
v   t   d   b   i   n   i   o   j   h   k   c   i   m   s   e   p   p   t   s   b
g   a   d   e   r   f   n   c   f   c   e   a   a   c   o   l   o   u   r   s   r
v   e   c   f   c   y   g   j   e   l   g   r   b   t   n   c   l   g   e   f   a
d   w   r   e   d   a   u   g   h   t   e   r   f   s   s   r   a   i   n   e   s
e   g   t   e   l   w   w   m   p   k   o   t   a   e   w   r   o   t   t   l   f
j   r   y   l   s   r   h   y   m   e   c   a   m   g   i   m   c   u   p   i   b
c   e   p   i   f   d   w   u   w   q   a   x   i   j   n   t   a   v   h   n   a
o   e   a   b   f   c   b   a   i   n   u   i   l   d   d   j   f   w   e   e   r
f   n   q   o   p   a   p   f   n   w   a   o   y   t   v   a   y   p   a   j   b
f   l   n   m   u   r   t   e   t   i   g   e   r   g   i   r   l   c   r   c   e
e   d   e   o   n   d   i   r   e   d   e   o   a   n   o   m   e   k   t   f   r
e   k   k   t   d   l   q   m   r   u   g   e   v   a   r   n   g   m   a   t   r
i   d   s   u   m   m   e   r   g   a   r   d   e   n   i   n   g   e   g   a   e
n   e   r   a   l   f   y   n   a   n   m   t   l   h   t   e   l   h   i   t   a
g   h   e   t   x   v   t   h   j   s   i   l   v   e   r   a   s   f   r   h   a
```

Comment: What does "final" word mean?

Comment: There should be a word from which there no more new clues touching it. I'll update the post. If needed I can add a *hint* for how many jumps you should expect before finishing.

Comment: So you want the word at the end of the longest chain? Because if you go down from the green square you get 'hat' which has no links. Also it seems like the words can touch anywhere.

Comment: Could you post a text version of the grid?

Comment: @Deusovi I would absolutely love to. Is there formatting, or a tool you'd recommend for providing that? From searching, I couldn't find a simple way to provide it in a text table on SE.

Comment: @HollyLeaves Apologies for the confusion with this, will definitely take this on board to try and improve next time. The first square should have two clues "hat" and "hard"; which should lead you to one other word (again which has two clues that go together, touching it). Some words may have extra words "touching", but there will be two unique clues that more clearly work together each time.

Comment: don't worry it's very interesting. I'm just being picky with the premises

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The final answer is

> AUTOMOBILE.

Here is the grid, with words highlighted:

> [image]

and the clues are:

> HARD HAT --> HELMET
>  VENOMOUS SNAKE --> COBRA
>  PRUNING, RAKING --> GARDENING
>  WINTER, SUMMER --> SEASONS
>  RAIN, WIND --> WEATHER
>  RED, GREEN --> COLOURS
>  STRIPED FELINE --> TIGER
>  FAMILY GIRL --> DAUGHTER
>  CAR, TAXI --> AUTOMOBILE

And there are no words coming off that final one, so we're done.

Comment: Just in the time I was writing a hint, terrified for how badly I'd given instructions. Absolutely perfect.

Comment: @Bilkokuya I was expecting the letters that each pair branched off of (or maybe the starting letters of the answers) to spell something - the only reason it took as long as it did was that I wasn't 100% sure that was the last word!

Comment: Ah, I'll definitely look at trying to add more of a "prize" secret in future - would definitely make it more rewarding. Thanks for solving anyway!

Comment: In the solution picture, why are the cells with `u` highlighted green?

Comment: @EngineerToast ...Because I had ctrl+F -ed `u`, and I forgot to unhighlight before screenshotting. Fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Partial Answer:

> [image]
>  So the clues are:
>  Hard Hat
>  Go Here
>  Venomous Cobra
>  but after that, there are eight words that are connected (depending on your definition of "connected"):
>  Mud, Hunt, Wet, Helmet, Bars, Pruning, See, and Snake.
>  Maybe someone else can make sense of all this.

Comment: Oh...I thought diagonals didn't count.....

Comment: And I thought you can't reuse letters too.....

Comment: It didn't specify in the question ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I've added a hint section that will hopefully clarify how to go about solving this. (Apologies for confusion caused, I'll hopefully be able to make things clearer in future)